# How and where to add angular material theme in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2, angular-material

How and where to add angular material theme?

> //Import a pre-built theme
>
> @import ‘~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css’;

Answer (score 0):

add `@import ‘~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css’;` in style.css under src folder

refer https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: Where is style.css in Ionic? 
Only app.scss is there and variables.scss under theme folder. I have tried at both locations.

Comment: I thought you are asking for Angular

Comment: Do you want to merge Ionic and angular material?

Comment: I have got solution. Placed css in assets folder.  Now working. Anyways Thanks.

Comment: Glad you fixed the issue.

Comment: How did you placed it?